# Why does CGContext not work in UITableViewCell on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Drawing lines doesn't work on iOS 14.

I create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

I want to draw two lines in the custom cell.

The code is below.

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect);

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.saveGState() // Save state. This includes transformations and clips

        context.setLineWidth(8.0)
        
        let lineColor = UIColor.red
        let bgColor = UIColor.lightGray

        context.setStrokeColor(bgColor.cgColor)
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 86.0, y: 42))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (86.0 + 120.0), y: 42))
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.strokePath()

        context.setLineWidth(8.0)
        context.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 86.0, y: 42))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (86.0 + 120.0 * self.lineScale ), y: 42))
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.strokePath()

        context.restoreGState() // Put back state. This includes transformations and clips
    }
```

It works well on iOS 12. It doesn't work on iOS 14. (I don't know whether it works on iOS 13).

I don't know what I can do to solve this issue.

Do you know the reason? Can you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be trying to override `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` for a table view cell to begin with. Cells have subviews, which have subviews, and the cell itself does a lot more than just "be there."

If you use `Debug View Hierarchy` you will see what's going wrong, and it will reinforce *why* that's a bad idea.

With `iOS 14` the cell structure changed and you should only be manipulating the cell's `.contentView` -- not the cell itself.

Much better to make that a custom view which is added to the content view.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't override the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` of a table cell. Instead, create a new custom view and add it to the cell's contentView, and draw in there.

You should instead create your `UIView` and add it as a subview of the contentView property. There are many questions/answers on here and across the web about `drawRect:` and `UITableViewCell`, most of them suggest that you do not do it.